# "Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors" ERROR

Tags: vmware

Attempting to upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and on restart I get this error.

```
Could not apply the stored configuration for monitors
```

This is a 64 bit version running in  Parallels 9 Desktop. I loose control of the cursor by clicking in the virtual machine. I 
can launch a bash shell by holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and get back to GUI by holding
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. I do not know how to close the error windows in the GUI Desktop!

I have a similar Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit running in VMware Fusion 6. I can close the error window with a close button that appears in this environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit the ESC key when the system boots. If there are multiple errors. Keep doing that till they all vanish.

Comment: The errors should probably not be happening in the first place - ignoring the errors is a bad thing.

Comment: Well, yes. They shouldn't. But they are. And he can't see the desktop to do anything. He can solve the issues after he can see his desktop.